# VBA Red Close Event did not close workbook properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a vba in which when a user opens the xlsm file, vba will set Application.Visible = False and shows user a userform to enter their credentials before setting Application.Visible = True become for user to use the excel.

While testing various scenarios, there is one that seems odd.
If user closed the Userform using the red cross at the top right corner before they successfully entered their credentials, and when I double click on the same xlsm file again, the Application becomes visible without the Userform.

I suspect when user closed with the red cross, only the UserForm is closed and the application was not. How can I make the red cross close the application so that when I double click on the xlsm again, it will run the marco for Userform to pop out?

Update:
The following did close the workbook with the red cross but I noticed even if user close the UserForm with CommandButton, it will still close the workbook. Is there a sub that only detects red cross?

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'Detecting user closing with top cross
    Sheet4.Range("B4") = CloseMode
    If CloseMode = 1 Then Cancel = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You can either disable the FormControlMenu's Close button or else catch the `UserForm_QueryClose` event (`CloseMode` will be equal to `vbFormControlMenu` if the Userform Close button was clicked).

Comment: Hi RBarryYoung, could you help give me an example how to set CloseMode equal vbFormControlMenu ? I have also updated my experiment.

Answer (score 0):

So the doc for the `_QueryClose` event is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event

I am not familiar with your code, but you probably want something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'Detecting user closing with top cross
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        ' 0 = vbFormControlMenu (the [X] was clicked)

        Cancel = 1      ' this keeps the form from closing

        '(or whatever you want to do here)
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: I had a typo in my code above (`Cancel = 0`) I have now corrected it to `Cancel = 1`.

Comment: HI RBarryYoung. Actually, I wanted the form and the workbook to close if user close the form with the [X] but without closing other workbooks that are already opened. If user enter in their correct credentials and click CommandButton, the form will close and then workbook will be visible.

Comment: @user3782604 Just replace it with whatever you want to do there.  Something like `ThisWorkbook.Close`?  And then you'd leave `Cancel = 0` too.